# How to add two columns to a table

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I have a table. I want to add two columns to this table.

I tried it like this:

```
SELECT * 
into
dbo.mytable_Audit
from dbo.mytable
```

But, I need two colums to mytable_Audit, how do I add them in sybase 15-2 ASE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get as much columns in your new table, as you have in the existing one. Name, type and order will be inherited from `dbo.mytable`.
To add an additional column to the output, just add a column to the select:

`select 0 as col1, * into dbo.mytable_AUDIT from dbo.mytable;`

This adds a column of type integer as the first column in the new table.

Answer (score 7):

You can also add columns to existing tables by using the `alter table` command.  For example, to add two new `int` columns to `mytable_Audit`, one with a default value, and the other as NULL:

```
alter table mytable_Audit add col1 int default 0, col2 int NULL
```